# Modified Cox method in calculating confidence intervals for Log-Normal distribution

Tags: statistics, distribution, confidence-interval

As titled, I want to find confidence intervals for something Log-Normally distributed.

I found this [paper](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1080/10691898.2005.11910638) online that suggests the use of `t` instead of the usual `z` (Section 3.4) for better coverage (Modified Cox method) when the number of observations is small. However, I do not understand how the degree of freedom for `t` is selected. The paper says:

> t, with degrees of freedom based on the d.f. for the estimate of (variance).

I'm unable to figure out how the author ended up with a degree of freedom of 5 in his example. Please help.

Comment: Bounty expiring soon!

Comment: The question looks off-topic to me. Probably, it should've been asked on https://stats.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: No luck in either